# How to save the value of the TextView?

Tags: android

I have a `textView` in my `MainActivity`. the value of the `textview` depends on the input of the user. When I navigate to the next `Activity` then go back to my `MainActivity`, the textView is empty. I've seen different examples and tried them all but nothing seems to work. What is wrong with my code?
This is my `MainActivity`.

```
 public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        TextView cart_items_tv;
        static Integer cartnum=0;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b2);
            final ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
            cart_items_tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_items);
            button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            new Downloader(MainActivity.this,url1,lv).execute();
            tv.setText("Category: Snacks and Drinks");
            v.setSelected(true);
            v.setPressed(true);
        }
    });

        public void cart_items(Integer num){
            cartnum = num +cartnum;
            if(cartnum == 0 || cartnum == 1 ) {
                cart_items_tv.setText("(" +String.valueOf(cartnum) + "item)");            
            } else
                cart_items_tv.setText("(" +String.valueOf(cartnum) + " items)");
       }

        @Override
        protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
            super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
            outState.putString("save",cartnum.toString());
        }

        @Override
        protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
            cart_items_tv.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("save"));
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**

This works when I press the back button. But when using the button of the second activity, via Intent, it doesn't work. Is there another way?

Comment: Don't use an intent to go back to the previous activity. Just call "finish()"

Comment: it somehow worked but I have a fragment in my MainActivity that shows before launching. When it goes back to the MainActivity, the fragment is still showing.

Comment: I used finish and just added some codes to the fragment to remove itself. thanks!